# Rotate global to local coordinate system by using orientation tensors of 2nd order

Tags: matlab, rotation, orientation, coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

I want to write a code in MATLAB to transform the global coordinate system onto a local one. More specifically, I have orientation tensors of 2nd order (3x3 matrix) in a global coordinate system and I want to rotate the global coordinate system to align the x-axis with the orientation.

The orientation tensor of 2nd order represents the orientation of a fiber, where the diagonal elements represent the degree of orientation with the x-, y- and z-axis. The off-diagonal elements stand for the tilt of the fiber from the axis.

An example of an orientation tensor of 2nd order:

```
a_ij= 
[0.2606 -0.1271 -0.0279
-0.1271  0.6832  0.0564
-0.0279  0.0564  0.0561]
```

This would mean that the fiber is mainly oriented in the y-axis with most tilt in the xy-plane.
My goal now is to rotate the coordinate system that way, that the x-axis is aligned with the highest value of the diagonal elements, which is 0.6832 in this example.

During my research I came to the conclusion that I have to solve the following equation in order to get the necessary angles:

```
a_primed=Q*a_unprimed*Q^T
```

Where a_primed would have the form:

```
[1 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0]
```

and Q, respectively it's transpose Q^T would be the rotation matrix. 
[Rotation matrix, source: http://www.continuummechanics.org/cm/transformmatrix.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAxfp.png)

Would this be the correct way to calculate the necessary angles? An alternative could be to use the principal axis theorem on the orientation tensor but I am a little bit lost with my problem here.

I hope you can point me towards the right direction.
Any help is much appreciated!

-Fabian